# Why does hitting the "Shift" key in a DGV throw an exception?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, shift

I've got this code in a custom class derived from DataGridView:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (char.IsNumber(Convert.ToChar(keyData)) || 
        char.IsControl(Convert.ToChar(keyData)) || 
        (keyData >= Keys.NumPad0 && keyData <= Keys.NumPad9) ||
        (keyData == Keys.Up) ||
        (keyData == Keys.Down) ||
        (keyData == Keys.Left) ||
        (keyData == Keys.Right) ||
        (keyData == Keys.Home) ||
        (keyData == Keys.PageDown) ||
        (keyData == Keys.PageUp) ||
        (keyData == Keys.Space) ||
        (keyData == Keys.Back) ||
        (keyData == Keys.Decimal))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I can enter data (numbers and .), and tab from cell to cell, but if I hit the "Shift" key, I get, *"System.OverflowException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Value was either too large or too small for a character.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Convert.ToChar(Int32 value)..."*

I assume this is the line that's causing the problem:

```
char.IsControl(Convert.ToChar(keyData))
```

...but why is Shift problematic, and what should I do to get it to disregard the Shift key (there's no reason for the user to press the Shift key in the DGV).

### UPDATE

I must admit I don't quite understand quetzalcoatl's answer, but I tried to apply it this way:

```
Keys specials = keyData & Keys.Modifiers; 
Keys keycode = keyData & ~Keys.Modifiers;

if (char.IsNumber(Convert.ToChar(keyData)) || 
    //char.IsControl(Convert.ToChar(keyData)) || 
    //(keyData == specials) || <-- didn't work
    //(keyData == keycode) ||  <-- didn't work
    (keyData != specials) ||
    (keyData != keycode) ||
    . . .
```

...and still get the same error. How can I apply the information he provided to solve the problem?

### UPDATE 2

I'm still struggling with this.

I've tried this:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    Keys keycode = keyData & ~Keys.Modifiers;

    if (keycode >= Keys.D0 && keycode <= Keys.D9 ||          
        keycode >= Keys.NumPad0 && keycode <= Keys.NumPad9 ||
        (keycode == Keys.Up) ||
        (keycode == Keys.Down) ||
        (keycode == Keys.Left) ||
        (keycode == Keys.Right) ||
    (keyData == Keys.Tab) ||
        (keycode == Keys.Tab) ||
        (keycode == Keys.Home) ||
        (keycode == Keys.PageDown) ||
        (keycode == Keys.PageUp) ||
        (keycode == Keys.Space) ||
        (keycode == Keys.Back) ||
        (keycode == Keys.Decimal))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

...and this approach:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        Keys keycode = keyData & ~Keys.Modifiers;

        bool isDigit = keycode >= Keys.D0 && keycode <= Keys.D9 ||
                       keycode >= Keys.NumPad0 && keycode <= Keys.NumPad9;
        bool isControl = (keyData & Keys.Modifiers) != Keys.None;

        if (isDigit ||
            isControl ||
            (keyData == Keys.Up) ||
            (keyData == Keys.Down) ||
            (keyData == Keys.Left) ||
            (keyData == Keys.Right) ||
        (keyData == Keys.Tab) ||
            (keyData == Keys.Home) ||
            (keyData == Keys.PageDown) ||
            (keyData == Keys.PageUp) ||
            (keyData == Keys.Space) ||
            (keyData == Keys.Back) ||
            (keyData == Keys.Decimal))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Both of them solve the Shift key causing an overflow, but both of them prevent a decimal from being entered. I don't understand that, as Decimal is being (supposedly) explicitly allowed. Everything else explicitly checked for is allowed (Home, PageUp, PageDown, etc.) - it's just the "." character that is being barred entry.

### UPDATE 3

Using the second approach above and replacing "Keys.Decimal" with "Keys.OemPeriod" works:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    Keys keycode = keyData & ~Keys.Modifiers;

    bool isDigit = keycode >= Keys.D0 && keycode <= Keys.D9 ||
                   keycode >= Keys.NumPad0 && keycode <= Keys.NumPad9;
    bool isControl = (keyData & Keys.Modifiers) != Keys.None;

    if (isDigit ||
        isControl ||
        (keyData == Keys.Up) ||
        (keyData == Keys.Down) ||
        (keyData == Keys.Left) ||
        (keyData == Keys.Right) ||
        (keyData == Keys.Home) ||
        (keyData == Keys.Tab) ||
        (keyData == Keys.PageDown) ||
        (keyData == Keys.PageUp) ||
        (keyData == Keys.Space) ||
        (keyData == Keys.Back) ||
        (keyData == Keys.OemPeriod))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not convert a `Keys` to `char`. This does not work. Test if it is a digit with

```
Keys code = keyData & ~Keys.Modifiers;

bool isDigit = code >= Keys.D0 && code <= Keys.D9 ||
               code >= Keys.NumPad0 && code <= Keys.NumPad9
```

Test if it is a control key with

```
bool isControl = (keyData & Keys.Modifiers) != Keys.None;
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because all I needed to do with my original code was incorporate this and replace "Keys.Decimal" with "Keys.OemPeriod" (see Update 3 to my original post).

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are translating the `Keys keyData` into Char in a wrong way. Convert.ToChar does not handle that.

The Keys enumeration contains `` mask that should be used to filter-out all modifiers like shift, alt, control:

```
Keys specials = keyData & Keys.Modifiers;
Keys keycode = keyData & ~Keys.Modifiers;
```

Now, the `keycode` is equal to exactly one of the normal A/B/C/... values defined in Keys, and `specials` is a bitset composed of Control/Alt/Shift modifiers.

The exact cause of the error is that while some of the 'lower key values' (a,b,c,..z,0-9, etc) are in fact equal/similar to ASCII codes, then the 'modifiers' are provided as a very high integer numbers that are bitwise-or'ed to the base key code:

```
Keys justA = Keys.A;
Keys theAandShift = Keys.A | Keys.Shift;
```

etc. This causes that 'A with Shift' has a numeric value completely absurdal in sense of ASCII or even Unicode .. and this is why you have to cut off the modifiers codes first!

edit:

```
Keys specials = keyData & Keys.Modifiers;
Keys keycode = keyData & ~Keys.Modifiers;

bool withShift = specials.HasFlag( Keys.Shift );
bool withControl = specials.HasFlag( Keys.Control );
bool withAlt = specials.HasFlag( Keys.Alt );

if(keycode == Keys.F1 && !withShift && !withControl && !withAlt)
    ; // it was plain F1 with no specials

else if(keycode == Keys.VolumeUp)
    ; // it was 'volume-up' key with any or none of the modifiers

else if(keycode >= Keys.A && keycode <= Keys.Z && withControl)
    ; // it was CTRL+Letter

else if(keycode >= Keys.D0 && keycode <= Keys.D9 && withShift)
    ; // it was SHIFT+Digit
```

and so on

Comment: Okay, I'm (reasonably) sure you're right, but I don't know how to apply what you're saying to solve my problem. I updated my post to show what I did try, which didn't change anything.

Comment: Please check the edit, I've included an if-tree showing how to check the keys and modifiers. Note that I've left the `specials` variable despite it is not important: only "filtered" `keycode` is needed, and the 'withshift' (and similar) can be read directly from the keydata. I mean, `specials.HasFlag(Keys.Shift)` is completely equal to `keyData.HasFlag(Keys.Shift)`. I've included the `specials` variable only to show how the highbit and lowbit parts of the keyData are organized. Highbits are the Modifiers (Shift,Control,Alt), and Lowbits are keycodes.

Comment: Btw this is exactly why in the Keys enumeration you have `Control` and `RControlKey LControlKey` members: Control is the Modifier, while L/RControlKey is the keycode. Hope this helps:)

Comment: Is this really the easiest way to "throw away" the Shift key?

Comment: Ah, and also please note that I deliberately **do not use** the Convert.ToChar(). Convert.ToChar is used for ASCII-like conversions, while the Keys enumeration has _some_ values that _does not match ASCII values_, thus Convert+Char.IsDigit and similar may fail. This is why it is better to just-compare to the Keys like I did.

Comment: No, I've shown you the full side of the problem. The simpliest way is to just filter out the modifiers: just include at the start of your method a line `keyData &= ~Keys.Modifiers;` and off you go, all high-bits are zeroed and gone. But still, the Convert.ToChar() is not guaranteed to work for all keys (like F12 or VolumeUp). They might work by accident though:) I mean, for A-Z and D0-D9 it probably will be ok.

Answer (score 2):

`Keys` can't be converted to a `char` like that.  If you look at `Shift` in the [Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) enumeration, it has a value of 65536 which is out of bounds for a `char`